# CSV field with newline character in a cell to import to excel

Tags: excel, csv, import

I've got a problem with data in CSV file to import into Excel.

I've parsed data from a website, and contain line break `<br>`, I convert this tag into `"\n"` and write to a CSV file. However, when I import this CSV file into Excel, the line-break display incorrectly. It results new line as a new row instead of a new line in a single cell itself.
Anyone have face this problem before? Really appreciate your suggestion.

Thanks!

`Edit`: Here the sample to demonstrate my situation

```
static void TestLine()
{
    string sampleData = "日찬양 까페에 올린 충격적인 <br>글코리아타임스";
    string formattedData = sampleData.Replace("<br>", "\n");
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\SampleData.csv", false, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(formattedData);
    }
}
```

I want the `sampleData` displaying in a cell, however, the result happens in 2 cells.

Comment: Can you provide a longer sample? Plus a quick SO search will reveal several CSV new-line questions

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like misformated CSV file. To handle this situation correctly, you will need to have a field with line break contained within quotation marks.

UPDATE after the sample:

This works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sampleData = "\"日찬양 까페에 올린 충격적인 <br>글코리아타임스\"";
    string formattedData = sampleData.Replace("<br>", "\n");
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\SampleData.csv", false, Encoding.Unicode))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(formattedData);
    }

}
```

You need to wrap the field in the quotation marks (")

Comment: I like the example - what language is that?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [CSV-1203 File Format Specification](http://mastpoint.curzonnassau.com/csv-1203), in particular the sections on "*End-of-Record Marker*" and "*Field Payload Protection*". Hopefully this should give clear guidance on the inner workings of the CSV file format.